# Capture scroll event on a particular jQuery Mobile Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How to capture the scroll event on a particular jQuery Mobile page?

**Page**

```
<div id='pg_remote-address-book' data-role='page'>
  <div data-role='content' id='pg_remote-address-book_content'>
    <ul data-role='listview' id='ul_address_list'>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

On pagebeforecreate, dynamically loading items inside the unordered list

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
  $("#ul_address_list").append("<li>"+i+"</li>");
}
```

**Capture Scrolling**

```
$('#pg_remote-address-book').scroll(function () {
  console.log('scrolled');
});
```

The scroll event is not getting captured.  How can I capture that?

If I put 'window' instead of '#pg_remote-address-book' then it is working.  But I want to capture the scroll event on a particular page.  Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Is the #pg_remote-address-book generated dynamically? 
Is it is, then maybe you should bubble the event up to another div and attach the handler to this one.

Comment: @fos.alex, no, the pg_remote-address-book is not generated dynamically. That is available in the index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to `scrollstart` or `scrollstop` events, and use `.on` to bind events.

```
$(document).on("scrollstart", function (e) {
  var active = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
  if (active == "pg_remote-address-book") {
    // Do something
  } else {
    // Do something else
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/YVfYN/)**